# Output using util.format on Node.js child process is not shown when done before process.exit()

Tags: node.js

I do have a node application that starts one. I am using the `spawn()` method instead of `fork()` to create the child instance because I sometimes need to start the child process using different node command line arguments (e.g. debug).

Consider the following example:

***master.js***

```
var child = require("child_process").spawn("node", ["child"]);
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout, { end: false });
```

***child.js***

```
console.log("Hello World!");
console.log(require("util").format("Hello World2!"));
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Error!");
    console.log(require("util").format("Error2!"));
    process.exit(1);
},2000);
```

When running ***master.js*** (on windows) the actual output is

```
Hello World!
Hello World2!
Error!
```

The "Error2!" message is missing and I don't understand why. Do you have any idea what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW, it also fails for me on Windows XP, but works on Debian. I'm using node 0.6.18 on both.

Comment: `console.log()` is asynchronous, so it is not guaranteed to complete before the process is killed by `process.exit(1)`.  Try using `util.log()` instead, which blocks the thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [process.exit(0): output disappears?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748164/process-exit0-output-disappears)