# process.exit(0): output disappears?

Tags: windows, node.js, emacs, elisp

Emacs lisp command calling `node hello.js`:

```
(call-process "node" nil t nil "hello.js")
```

Two variants of `hello.js`:

- `hello_1.js`:

  ```
  console.log('Hello world!');
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Hello world!
  0
  ```
- `hello_2.js`:

  ```
  console.log('Hello world!');
  process.exit(5);
  ```

  Output (no output from log statement!):

  ```
  5
  ```

*What is the reason that `process.exit(5)` causes output to be suppressed?*

Notes:

- I experienced the problem in *GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of
  2013-03-17 on MARVIN* in combination with *Node.js v0.10.18*, running on
  *Windows XP/SP3/32*.
- I tried [EShell](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryEshell) to execute the node command line: no output
- `process.exit()` calls low level `process.reallyExit()`, which causes the problem:
  no output

  `process.reallyExit()` is implemented in C++:

  ```
  void Exit(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    HandleScope scope(node_isolate);
    exit(args[0]->IntegerValue());
  }
  ```

  [...]

  ```
  NODE_SET_METHOD(process, "reallyExit", Exit);
  ```

Comment: `node -p "console.warn('Hello World!!');process.exit(0);"` output `"Hello World!!"` in eshell on my Ubuntu 12.04(Emacs 24.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, I figured it out myself. First of all, I discovered that a delay causes 
the output to appear:

`hello_3.js`:

```
console.log('Hello world!');
setTimeout(function () {
    process.exit(5);
}, 1000);
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
5
```

So I double checked Node.js documentation for `console`, and [found](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console):

> The console functions are synchronous when the destination is a terminal or a
>   file (to avoid lost messages in case of premature exit) and asynchronous when
>   it's a pipe (to avoid blocking for long periods of time).

Then I decided to make sure that no pipe is used and wrote a batch script
`hello_2.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
node hello_2.js >test
TYPE test
```

Output when calling the script with `(call-process "cmd.exe" nil t nil "/C"
"hello_2.bat")`:

```
Hello world!
0
```

(return value is 0 instead of 5, but I don't care about that)

To answer my question:

1. It looks like `call-process` in Emacs on Windows uses a pipe for retrieving
   output from programs.

   As I also mentioned EShell: It does not seem to be recognized as a
   terminal by Node.js on Windows, and possibly EShell internally uses `call-process` or
   similar to run programs.
2. Detection of a pipe as destination for standard output causes `console.log`
   to be run asynchronously.
3. `process.exit(5)` in Node.js on Windows seems to discard all scheduled
   asynchronous tasks, and thus no output is generated.

   This assumption is supported by the outcome of desperately directing output to a
   pipe inside the Windows command prompt:

   ```
   C:\Temp> node hello_2.js | MORE

   C:\Temp>
   ```

Finally, I found out that the issue is [known](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3584) since about a year ago (as of September 2013).